# permission denied when adding ssh to gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I was trying to add an ssh key for gitlab to pavlovia.
I did

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my_email"

pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub #pasted to pavlovia ssh keys
```

My .ssh/config looks like this:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal

Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

But when I do:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

This gives me

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What did i do wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Try 
`ssh -i <path to private key> -T git@gitlab.com`

Comment: Still permission denied:( what does this command do?

Comment: ` ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519. -T git@gitlab.com ` uses specified private key for the connection. Did you paste your public key in gitlab.com ssh keys under settings?

Comment: i see. and yeah i did but still can't connect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops i figured it out... the host should be git.pavlovia.org

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `Host *` entry forces the key to be `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, I would remove that section, for testing, in order to see if the relevant section applies:

```
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
   User git
```

Note that I have added the user, so your test becomes:

```
ssh -T gitlab.com
```

This assumes you need to contact GitLab, not a private instance like `git.pavlovia.org`.